# How to change background colour of td in table based on their value in array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I need help with this code..

This is table:

```
<table id="tabela_zaduzi_plombe" class="table-responsive table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer font-size-13">
  <thead>
    <tr class="boja-reda">
      <th class="width-50"></th>
      <th class="align-center width-50"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /></th>
      <th class="width-300"><?php echo __("SERIJSKI BROJ"); ?></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php //debug($lista_slobodnih_plombi); die; ?>
  <?php foreach($lista_slobodnih_plombi as $lista_sp): ?>
    <?php foreach($lista_sp as $lista): ?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="align-center td_checkbox"><input type="checkbox"  name="link-cbx" class="checkItem" autocomplete="on" id="<?php echo $lista;?>" data-sb_plombe="<?php echo $lista;?>"/></td>
      <td class="sbr"><?php echo $lista;?></td>

    </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is output of array:

```
    array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => '222222222',
        (int) 1 => '222222223',
        (int) 2 => '222222224',
        (int) 3 => '222222225'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => '333333333',
        (int) 1 => '333333334'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        (int) 0 => '444444444',
        (int) 1 => '444444445',
        (int) 2 => '444444446',
        (int) 3 => '444444447',
        (int) 4 => '444444448'
    )
)
```

I need to change background color so that every member of array has its own color.

**Example**: If I have 3 arrays, I need 3 different colors.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding background color to td, you need to generate a random color for each array key. Here is the function to create colors array with key and values ( color code)

```
function getColors($array) {
        // init array
        $colors = array();
        // count of number of random colors to generate
        if(count($array)>0){
            // get the keys of passed array ( will be help full if the passed array is associative array )
            $array_keys = array_keys($array);
            $chars = "ABCDEF0123456789";
            $size = strlen($chars);
            foreach($array_keys as $value){
                for( $j = 0; $j < 6; $j++ ) {
                    // generate a random color for each key of passed array
                    $colors[$value] .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $colors;
    }
```

Now add bgcolor for td.

```
<?php 
   // call the function to get random colors
    $colors = getColors($lista_slobodnih_plombi);?>

  <?php foreach($lista_slobodnih_plombi as $key=>$lista_sp): ?>
    <?php foreach($lista_sp as $lista): 

    ?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="align-center td_checkbox"><input type="checkbox"  name="link-cbx" class="checkItem" autocomplete="on" id="<?php echo $lista;?>" data-sb_plombe="<?php echo $lista;?>"/></td>
      <td class="sbr" bgcolor="<?php echo '#'.$colors[$key];?>"><?php echo $lista;?></td>

    </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note: background colors will change for every page load.

Comment: Woooow thank you, that helped a lot! :)